# Java, generate a text

Tags: java, string, hashtable, stringbuffer

I have a problem with a part of my program. In the following code 27 is the number of letters of our alphabet; list_extended is an objcet of type Hashtable(StringBuffer,Integer), containing all strings of length n+1 in the text with the number of occurrences; list_extended is built correctly because I have already controlled this part. The aim is : for every repetition of the outer for we take te last n characters of text generated, and for every letter of the alphabet we count the number of occurrences in list_extended of the n+1 characters obtained by adding the character to the last n characters of text_generated; then we choose the letter with the biggest number of occurrences.  The result I obtain is that occurrences contains all 0's, why ? The code

```
        int index;
        int[] occurrences = new int[27];
        StringBuffer curr_word;
        for(int x = 0; x < m; x++){   // m is the number of characters the user wants to add
            curr_word = new StringBuffer(text_generated.substring(x, x+n)); // n is an integer entered previously, initially text_generated is formed by n characters
            for(int j = 0; j < 27; j++){
                if(list_extended.get(curr_word.append(array[j]))==null)
                    occurrences[j] = 0;
                else
                    occurrences[j] =(int) list_extended.get(curr_word.append(array[j]));
            }
            index = 0;
            for(int j = 1; j < 27; j++){
                if(occurrences[j] > occurrences[index])
                    index = j;
            }   
            text_generated = text_generated.append(array[index]);
        }
                    System.out.println("The text generatd is \n" + text_generated.toString());
```

Comment: Is it because you don't increase the index? It's very hard to see through the code like this.

Comment: which index do you mean  ?

Comment: text_generated = text_generated.append(array[index]);

Comment: First of all, you need to use an immutable class instead of `StringBuffer`. So use `String` as key in your HashMap. Why? because when you use a mutable object as key then once the value of the key changes, you will not find the value!

Comment: `StringBuilder` doesn't override `equals()` and `hashcode()`, so it doesn't have much sense `list_extended.get()` because you'll always get the same curr_word object, as the default implementation of `equals()` is to compare if two objects are the same (`e == other`)

Comment: @morgano but list_extend.get() returns an Integer, not a StringBuffer

Comment: Is not what it returns, but the argument you use in `list_extended.get()` (a `StringBuffer`)

Comment: Unless you really have to use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer and HashMap instead of Hashtable. As mentioned, Map.get(StringBuffer) will only return a match for the same StringBuffer/StringBuilder, not anything with the same contents.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey so how can I search a match for something with the same content ?

Comment: Now you're asking Peter to tell you what Multithreader has already told you.

Comment: Use a `Map<String, ValueType>` and do a lookup with `map.get(stringBuilder.toString())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you create new object `curr_word`, but you didn't put it in `list_extended`, so every time you check

`if(list_extended.get(curr_word.append(array[j]))==null)`

will be `null` and

`occurrences[j]` will be **0**

Comment: list_extend is the list of occurrrences of n+1 characters strings of another text, not text generated; besides curr_word 's length is n, not n+1

Comment: and that's the problem, you create new StringBuffer, but its not in list_extend, so you cannot find it in list_extend, actually what you need to check is String it self, not the StringBuffer. why not change list_extend to Hashtable<String,Integer> ?